# How to test a .catch() block with chai?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to reach a good coverage with my codebase e2e tests, so I want to test `.catch()` code too.
My APIs use node.js and mongoose.
For testing I use chai and mocha.

I'm trying something like this:

*file src/controllers/user.controller.js:*

```
const User = require("../models/user.model");

const getUser = async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({name: req.name});
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    // THIS IS THE CODE I WANT TO TEST
    console.error(`Error finding user ${req.name}:`, err);
    return res.status(err.code).json({ message: err });
  }
}
```

*file src/models/user.model.js:*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: "Name is required",
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

*file test/user.test.js:*

```
 const chai = require("chai");
 const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
 const spies = require("chai-spies");
 const User = require("../src/models/user.model");
 chai.use(chaiHttp);
 chai.use(spies);
 chai.should();

 describe("should handle mongoose errors", function() {
    describe("faulty User.findOne method", function() {
      const _User_findOne_Backup = User.findOne;
      beforeEach(function() {
        // THIS FUNCTION SHOULD OVERLOAD REAL findOne FUNCTION, BUT IT DOES NOT!
        User.findOne = function() {
          return Promise.reject("forced error");
        };
      });
      afterEach(function() { // restore the real function after each test
        User.findOne = _User_findOne_Backup; 
      }); 

      it("signup should respond with a server error", function() {
        const spy = chai.spy();
        return chai
          .request(server)
          .post("/api/getUser")
          .send({name: "Alice"})
          .then(spy)
          .catch((err) => {
            const res = err.response;
            res.should.have.status(500);
          })
          .then(() => {
            spy.should.not.have.been.called();
          })
        ;
      });
    });
  });
```

The problem is that the fake `User.findOne()` method is never called in my tests: the original mongoose `findOne` method is called, which succeeds, so the `getUser` method never throws, making my test fail...

Probably I'm missing something obvious, but really I can't find it... :-(
If some more code or context is needed, please ask for it...

**UPDATE**:
Following @Bergi suggestion, I added full info about my (simplified) models and required modules...

Comment: Well what is `User` in *user.controller.js* and what is `User` in *test/user.test.js*? Apparently they do not refer to the same object, but since you are not showing us how you initialise those variables we can't tell what's wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I've added User model (simplified) specification to the question... However, the User in *user.controller.js* and the User in *test/user.test.js* are absolutely the same class...

Comment: Yeah if they're both pointing to the same model instance, this definitely should work. I don't think mocha does weird things with the module system where it evaluates the code twice?

Comment: For debugging, I'd probably place a `console.log` next to `mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);`, one next to the `getUser` definition, and one inside `getUser` - are they getting hit as expected?

Comment: I did place a console.log next to `mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)`: it's hit as expected. And the same after `getUser` definition and inside it...  
I didn't specify my code works just fine for use cases under test...
The fake `User.findOne` function is defined, but it's never called...

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me.

E.g.

`user.model.js`:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: "Name is required",
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

`user.controller.js`:

```js
const User = require("./user.model");

const getUser = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error finding user ${req.body.name}:`, err);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: err });
  }
}

module.exports = {
  getUser
}
```

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const userController = require('./user.controller');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json())
app.post('/api/getUser', userController.getUser)

module.exports = app;
```

`user.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
const User = require("./user.model");
const server = require('./server');
chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.should();

describe("should handle mongoose errors", function () {
  describe("faulty User.findOne method", function () {
    const _User_findOne_Backup = User.findOne;
    beforeEach(function () {
      User.findOne = function () {
        return Promise.reject("forced error");
      };
    });
    afterEach(function () {
      User.findOne = _User_findOne_Backup;
    });

    it("signup should respond with a server error", function () {
      return chai
        .request(server)
        .post("/api/getUser")
        .send({ name: "Alice" })
        .catch((err) => {
          const res = err.response;
          res.should.have.status(500);
        })
        ;
    });
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  should handle mongoose errors
    faulty User.findOne method
Error finding user Alice: forced error
      ✓ signup should respond with a server error


  1 passing (21ms)

--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files           |    89.19 |      100 |    88.89 |    88.57 |                   |
 server.js          |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 user.controller.js |       80 |      100 |      100 |       75 |               6,7 |
 user.model.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 user.test.js       |    88.89 |      100 |    85.71 |    88.89 |             26,27 |
--------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

package versions:

```json
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chai-http": "^4.3.0",
"mongodb": "^3.6.3",
"mongoose": "^5.11.9",
"express": "^4.17.1"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your post is correct, and it answers my question. To be honest I came with your same solution just a while after posting... My issue is now a little more subtle... What if I have *two* `findOne` in the same endpoint and I want to test both? It's a situation that really happens to me, but I don't add the code here because it is a bit too complex and difficult to strip down...